# Waterproof Fan Failing In A Chamber With 100% Relative Humidity

Tags: current, driver, fan, high-current, humidity

So I've built a aeroponic tower that uses an ultrasonic atomizer instead of spray nozzles. This approach is called "fogponics" across the hydroponic community.

My Problem is that I have to run a fan within the atomizing environment which requires the fan to be in contact with 100% humidity at all times. The fans purpose is to recirculate the generated vapor continuously. This of course brings into question the need for a waterproof fan.

I bought 2 from ebay recently and was advised to run them at 12V instead of 24V to keep the current from going too high due to the added drag of the water that would kill the driver if it was running at 24V.

Here's what I bought: http://www.ebay.ca/itm/40mm-20mm-New-Case-Cooling-Fan-24V-Waterproof-to-IP55-2-Wire-Ball-Brgs-376-/382060138074?hash=item58f48f0e5a:g:IE4AAOSwBOtZAQxW

The 2D image below shows my implemented design (Right) and an older version that better illustrates how the air circulates(Left)
[image: 2D]

Here are a few shots of my prototype:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

The waterproof fan lasted around 55 hours cycling on for 2 mins and off for 1. I noticed that the sound changed towards the 40 hour mark; It started to lower in pitch and would fluctuate irregularly between it's original pitch the lower pitch every 2-10 seconds.

The fan would not start again after it's untimely demise.

What do you folks think is happening? I could really use a solution or suggestion to help me through this because I'm at my wits end and thinking about a redesign is disheartening when I'm so close!

Comment: Can't you design things so that your fan accelerates dry air and directs it into the misting area to move the mist? Are you currently pulling misted air through the fan itself?

Comment: You might want to look at squirrel cage fans too

Comment: @Jonk, most fogponic designs input dry air as you describe, but the trouble with this is that you will be pressurizing the closed misting chamber - when this happens, the air and vapor will escape through any holes or gaps it can and reducing the available fog density within the chamber. This will also waste the nutrient solution as well as introduce it to the surrounding breathable air which poses health risks. 

Yes, the misted air is both pulled and pushed through the fan. This keeps the fog localized within the chamber because there is no new pressure being added. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: We (or at least I) cannot see your images.  Edit and insert them onto this site.

Comment: You should consider a Tangential fan like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/ebm-papst-QG-030-DC-Tangential-Blower-QG030-EA19-12-/111817841665. These can be driven on a long shaft from outside your fog'd area then you don't need to worry about a waterproof motor.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Thanks for letting me know! It seems google drive has some problems here. I've edited in the new photos; have a look.

Comment: @JackCreasey These are very interesting. The only cause for concern is the scale and shape of the tubing I'm using. I can't see how I could apply a fan like that to what I have now. I think a fan that houses the motor outside is a good solution though. Do you see a way I could go about it with the photos I've re-uploaded?

Comment: Bear in mind that water vapour is not the same as liquid water.  Water vapour can slip through tiny gaps, when water droplets would just run off.  So a fan that is splashproof may not withstand long exposure to fog.

Comment: You can buy Tangential fans without motors that could fit right across your base. You could fit a motor directly to a shaft (or belt drive) and use simple rubber seals to the inner side of the bearing. Since you have no pressure inside the containment area it won't leak. You could also use an oven fan: http://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1om7vLpXXXXbXXpXXq6xXFXXXN/220V-50Hz-VDE-UL-CE-certified-Electric.jpg ...easily sourced and all you need is a rubber seal on the shaft.

Answer (score 3):

I think the old adage of you get what you pay for applies here. Select a professional quality fan with IP67 or IP68 ratings made for the application. A Sanyo Denki [(link)](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/s/sanyo-denki/waterproof-fans) waterproof fan would seem to fit the requirements, for example.

Answer (score 3):

- IP55 - weather-proof.
- IP57 - watertight.
- IP65 - Able to protect against water jets
- IP66 - Able to protect against powerful water jets
- IP67 - Able to protect against Immersion up to 1 m

From your link.

> WATERPROOF to IP55 - These fans were modified at the mynewfan shop to exceed IP55 conditions, that is to say the fan does not fail due to water or dust ingress.  The electronics and the field coils were encapsulated in a UL recognized, MIL-I-46058C polyurethane.  A synthetic grease, used on Mil/Aero Fans, has been added to the bearing shields and shaft to prevent corrosion.  Polyurethane was also brushed on the stator to retard corrosion.

Not sure how good a job Joe at the mynewfan shop does, but as Glenn says you really do get what you pay for.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I'll look around for fans with higher ratings.